# Mouse stopped clicking in CentOS running in Virtual Box

Tags: centos, centos7, centos7.6

I have an CentOS 7 VM in the VirtualBox 6 running on Windows. I have just installed it and immediately updated whole system (sudo yum update), as result kernel version 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7 was installed.

After I rebooted and logged in into the system, mouse started working strange. Mouse can be moved, application menu can be opened, but inside it no reaction in mouse movements. Also most of UI doesn't react to mouse clicks. I've searched internet and tried various ways, but nothing helps.

It is fresh install, I don't have VirtualBox guest additions installed yet. But right after installation everything worked and stopped to work after update. Does anyone know what may be the reason and how to solve this?

Rebooting with previous kernel doesn't help. Maybe something with X.org? It was updated too. But I don't see any error in the /var/log/Xorg.0.log

**Update #1:** This https://www.quora.com/Why-can-I-move-my-mouse-but-cannot-click-in-a-VirtualBox-with-Ubuntu recipe have helped. I have create mouse configuration file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-mouse.conf` with content like this

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "6 7"
EndSection
```

Actual mouse device path (`/dev/input/event3`) was taken from the latest `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` -- look for "VirtualBox mouse integration".

**Update #2:** I have found that if you log in first time, then somehow run console, and restart desktop manager service (sudo service gdm restart) - it will get you back to login screen - then everything works good on the second time login, even without such file. Can't explain myself what can be the reason.

**Update #3:** RH acknowledged the issue and works on the fix.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3893421

**Update #4:** After today's update problem has gone.
Now I'm having:

```
Linux centos7 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 18 15:06:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Excellent find.  One edit -- it is /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d, not /ec/...

Comment: Vbox 6.0.2, CentOs 7.6, same problem.  Tried your .conf.  While it appears to have worked, the performance of the VM dropped from real-time to doing everything in bursts.  Needed to remove the file to get back to usefulness.  Am continuing to investigate.

Comment: @rip... I have found that if you log in first time, then somehow run console, and restart desktop manager service (sudo service gdm restart) - it will get you back to login screen - then everything works good on the second time login, even without such file. Can't explain myself what can be the reason.

Comment: @rip... Please share here any findings, if you manage to solve this or understand what is the reason of the issue.

Comment: @ivan.ukr - Your "update" worked for me as a solution, no performance problems. CentOS 7.6.1810.

Comment: FYI, this bug is being investigated : https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3714911   and  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3893421

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: Having the same problem. You should post the "update" as a solution and accept the answer so I can upvote it!

Comment: @tekHedd posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a more recent update problem goes away. First known by me kernel version where the problem has gone:

```
Linux centos7 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 18 15:06:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64  GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I'm running the same kernel version and still having this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have the similar issue with Centos 7.4 on VirtualBox 5 recently.

Once I left-click and start working on an application, I could not left-click on any other part nor applications to switch the focus.

My work-around is to right click the mouse on the stuck application twice.  A context menu will pop up and go away.  Then I can left-click any other parts of the desktop.  Of course, doing this every time when one wants to switch the focus is still annoying but at least workable.